# How to pass items to loop using Jinja2/Flask?

Tags: python, list, loops, flask, jinja2

I want to pass a list of pages and loop it in Jinja2 to show all pages of my website. I use Flask to construct and run the app. I followed the official flask documentation, together with [this tutorial](http://pycourse.com/posts/2013/Jul/16/Templating%20and%20Jinja2/). However when I try to pass the list and try to loop over it, it does not appear in the rendered html.

*What am I doing wrong? How to properly pass the list and loop over it using `base.html` as a template?*

Here is my code with a dummy page list hardcoded:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    page_list = ['Eins', 'Zwei']
    return render_template('base.html', pages=page_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8000)
```

And `base.html`, located in `/templates/`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>All the nice pages</h1>
{% for page in pages %}
<p>{{ page }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app and browse to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, this is what I get:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<h1>All the nice pages</h1>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something isn't right. Your code works as you'd expect it to. Did you change `app.py` after starting the application? You'll need to reload it. I'd suggest adding `debug=True` to your call to `app.run()`.

Comment: The code works fine , restart your server

Comment: I tried your app and it works just fine, it prints both the page lists to the browser. Reload the app or stop the simultaneous app running in background.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but watch the placement of your HTML tags. Your `h1` appears outside the `body` tag.

Comment: @all! Thanks, restarting the server did the trick...

Answer (score 2):

This code is totally valid. The important thing is to restart the server if you do changes to lists or dictionaries.

Apart from that, in Flask you can pass any type that is built into Python, be it a `list`, a `dictionary` or a `tuple`.

Here are short example for each of the types that pass more or less the same content:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

adictionary = {'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2}
alist = ['Eins', 'Zwei', 'Drei']
atuple = ('spam', 'eggs')

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html', pages=alist)


@app.route('/tuple/')
def tuple():
    return render_template('base.html', pages=atuple)


@app.route('/dict/')
def adict():
    return render_template('base.html', pages=adictionary)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. I use Sublime Text 3 and realized that I didn't automatically convert tabs to spaces. Once I made that change in the user settings, and reran the script, it output the list correctly.